# I can't import securesocial.core.java.BaseUserService; When installing securesocial in play framework

Tags: playframework-2.0, securesocial

I've done the following:

1. I've copied the contents of module-code/ into the modules/securesocial/ folder in my app root.
2. I've updated my Build.scala to be the following:

   ```
   import sbt._
   import Keys._
   import PlayProject._

   object ApplicationBuild extends Build {

   val appName         = "XXXXXX"
   val appVersion      = "1.0-SNAPSHOT"

   val appDependencies = Seq(
     // Add your project dependencies here,
   )

   val ssDependencies = Seq(
     // Add your project dependencies here,
     "com.typesafe" %% "play-plugins-util" % "2.0.1",
     "org.mindrot" % "jbcrypt" % "0.3m"
   )

   val secureSocial = PlayProject(
       "securesocial", appVersion, ssDependencies, mainLang = SCALA, path = file("modules/securesocial")
   ).settings(
     resolvers ++= Seq(
       "jBCrypt Repository" at "http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/",
       "Typesafe Repository" at "http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases/"
     )
   )

   // Only compile the bootstrap bootstrap.less file and any other *.less file in the stylesheets directory
   def customLessEntryPoints(base: File): PathFinder = (
       (base / "app" / "assets" / "stylesheets" / "bootstrap" * "bootstrap.less") +++
       (base / "app" / "assets" / "stylesheets" / "bootstrap" * "responsive.less") +++
       (base / "app" / "assets" / "stylesheets" / "bootstrap" * "tooltip.less") +++
       (base / "app" / "assets" / "stylesheets" * "*.less")
   )

   val main = PlayProject(appName, appVersion, appDependencies, mainLang = JAVA).settings(
     // Add your own project settings here
     lessEntryPoints <<= baseDirectory(customLessEntryPoints)
   ).dependsOn(secureSocial).aggregate(secureSocial)
   ```
3. I've added `include "securesocial.conf"` to application.conf.

I can't figure out why it still gives me an error :(. The error I get is:

not found: value securesocial

Comment: The demo works fine for me, I've gotten it to work, but for some reason I can't reconcile the demo with my own project.

I get `The import securesocial cannot be resolved`

Answer (score 3):

The module is available as a downloadable dependency now.  If you change your Build.scala file to something like the sample below it should work:

```
object ApplicationBuild extends Build {
val appName         = "myapp"
val appVersion      = "1.0-SNAPSHOT"

val appDependencies = Seq(
    "securesocial" % "securesocial_2.9.1" % "2.0.6"
)
val main = PlayProject(appName, appVersion, appDependencies, mainLang = SCALA).settings(
  resolvers += Resolver.url("SecureSocial Repository", url("http://securesocial.ws/repository/releases/"))(Resolver.ivyStylePatterns)
)
}
```

There are detailed instructions on how to install it on [the project user guide](http://securesocial.ws/guide/overview.html).

Comment: Also if you are using eclipse, you need to run `play eclipse` and refresh your eclipse project to let eclipse find your dependencies.